# How to extend a pair of RCA cable and improve audio quality at the same time?

Tags: speakers, audio, cable

I have a 2.1 speaker system that I have been using for over 6-7 years or so. Recently I have decided to mount the two satellites on the wall, but there is a problem with the length of cables. I have to extend (to 2.5 meters) the cables that are RCA type. I think of two ways of accomplishing it.

- I can mount a female RCA connector on satellite speakers' cases. This way I can remove RCA cables from the satellites easily in the future. I have run across some articles online claiming that noise production between RCA male and RCA female is a known issue. How much it reflects the truth?
- I may just solder one end of the RCA cable directly to the speaker as it is done by the manufacturer of this system.

In both of these methods, how using thicker RCA cables may change the sound quality? Is there something I should know about soldering the audio wires to get the best results? What type of RCA cable is the best (in terms of buddeg and technology) for such an old basic system upgrade?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site Karel. General audio equipment questions tend to be seen as off-topic here - maybe this is one for electronics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @topomorto Maybe you are right. I posted here because I had seen similar technical questions here. Thanks

Comment: Yes, It can be a bit inconsistent - maybe someone will pop up with an answer. And I noticed you're not a new user, apologies for the 'welcome'(!)

Comment: Clearly the only solution is to use these http://www.amazon.com/Wireworld-Platinum-Eclipse-Biwired-Speaker/dp/B00CHSRKJW/ref=sr_1_1?s=aht&ie=UTF8&qid=1462710698&sr=1-1  cables.   Anyway, RCA connections are fine so long as you keep them clean, including polishing off oxidation.   For a setup like yours, neither the resistive loss nor the inductance frequency loss is likely to be noticeable w/ standard speaker wire.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The product you mentioned seems like to be an extremely cheap solution ))

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Do you think I could get those in 10m lengths? My Radio Shack rears just don't sound as good as I feel they ought & I'm certain you've found my ideal solution ;)

Comment: This could be on topic on electronics, but not as it currently stands. Have a look at the questions over there and you'll see required format. Be aware thickness of cable is (almost) entirely irrelevant to signal quality for audio.

Answer (score 2):

The main criterion for choosing your cable is length.  It should have sufficient of this to reach the speakers in their new location.  If they don't, it's a showstopper.

Apart from that, don't fuss.  If you use an extra plug/socket stage, turn the plugs occasionally to make sure corrosion isn't adding resistance.  Once a year should be fine.